# If $\binom {28}{2r} : \binom {24} {2r-4} = 225:11$, find $r$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I want to know what should be a good and efficient approach to solve the given question (and similar questions):

If $\binom {28}{2r}  : \binom {24} {2r-4} = 225:11$, **find r**.

Comment: Easiest approach is to experiment. $r=1, 2$ not going to work clearly. $r=3$will not work as you will have a $23$ in denominator. $r=4$ will probably work. This has the potential of getting a $11$ in the denominator. Try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Use $$\binom {n}{k}=\binom {n}{n-k}$$ to get

$$\frac {\binom {28}{2r}}{\binom {24}{2r-4}}=\frac {\binom {28}{28-2r}}{\binom {24}{28-2r}}=\frac {225}{11}$$

Put $28-2r=k$

Hence $$\frac {\binom {28}{k}}{\binom {24}{k}}=\frac {225}{11}$$

Comment: Good approach. Perhaps preface with "Since $\binom nk = \binom n{n-k},$"

Comment: @Joffan Thanks for suggestion. Edited the answer.

Comment: ... and from there you can drop to factorials and track eg. how to eliminate multiples of $13$ from the expression...